# How to prevent div from triggering its parent's mousemove when it's hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some media. Above that, I have a group of controls that I want to hide when the user's mouse is idle. Then I want them to reappear if the user moves the mouse.

My problem is that when the controls go away, they trigger a mousemove event on the parent. This causes the controls to reappear.

Here is the JS code:

```
(function($) {
  var timer = null;
  $('.outer').mousemove(function() {
    $('.inner').fadeIn('slow');

    if (timer) {
      window.clearInterval(timer);
    }
    timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
      $('.inner').fadeOut('slow');
    }, 3000);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

And here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8oduhs96/

Right now the fiddle is structured to look more like my project. I don't have a lot of flexibility for changing markup so a JS and/or CSS solution is preferred.

You can uncomment the lower block of CSS to see that the problem only happens when your mouse is over the blue area.

Comment: I'd try adding and removing a class on the parent based on if the menu is hidden or not. Then, basing the hover on if the parent has that class or not.

Comment: I don't get the problem, when you don't move the mouse, the menu disapear, isn't what you need? Also, consider an addClass/removeClass and CSS transition like this https://jsfiddle.net/8oduhs96/7/

Comment: @romuleald The problem is that the menu reappears immediately without having moved the mouse. Your fiddle doesn't have that problem because the menu isn't fully removed, it's just alpha'ed out. This is, IMO, more acceptable than using a timeout after hiding. If you type up an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS and opacity/visibility to hide your elements, they will not trigger a modification of DOM (as a `display:none/block;` effect from jQuery `fadeIn/fadeOut`)

https://jsfiddle.net/8oduhs96/8/

Comment: This is great but it removes the fadeOut effect. Is there a quick CSS fix for that as well?

Comment: increase the value inside the transition property in .inner.Take a look at the MDN article to understand the power of transition https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Answer (score 0):

You could add a check to see if the element is visible.

```
(function($) {
  var timer = null;
  $('.outer').mousemove(function() {
    console.log('MouseOver');
    if($('.inner').is(':visible')){
      console.log('Triggered');
      $('.inner').fadeIn('slow');

      if (timer) {
        window.clearInterval(timer);
      }
      timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
        $('.inner').fadeOut('slow');
      }, 3000);
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I tested in fiddle and this doesn't allow .inner to show ever again. I'll update the question to clarify.

Comment: You could add an else statement to the visible check so that if it isn't visible it will fadeIn. I would recommend you also set that on a timeout so that it won't instantly show up and trigger it to hide again.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael suggests in a comment on his answer, I solved this from a UX standpoint by using a timeout.

I would still prefer a solution that doesn't involve a timeout if someone else out there knows how.

```
(function($) {
  var timer = null;

  function setupOuter() {
    $('.outer').mousemove(function() {
      $('.inner').fadeIn('slow');  
      $('.outer').off('mousemove');
    });
  }
  setupOuter();

  $('.inner').mousemove(function() {
    if (timer) {
      window.clearInterval(timer);
    }
    timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
      $('.inner').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        window.setTimeout(setupOuter, 500);
      });
    }, 3000);
  });
})(jQuery);
```